# Better Way for remote debugging Odoo/Python in docker container with Eclipse + Pydev?

Tags: python, debugging, docker, remote-debugging, odoo

Is there any better way to describe the below way

http://pydev.org/manual_adv_remote_debugger.html

Without put the below things

```
import sys;
sys.path.append(r'path_to\pydev\plugins\org.python.pydev\pysrc')

import pydevd
```

without using the breakpoint with mouse click and put it same as below source code location

```
pydevd.settrace('10.0.0.1')
```

working good in above way but mouseclick for breakpoint would be so much better in our situation as making the code more complex.

Is there any better way to do job of debugging in python/Odoo ??

Comment: If you need remote debugging why not trying PyCharm or PyCharmCE(free edition)? It's really great!

Comment: because eclipse rocks :-)

Answer (score 0):

I always use logging to debug my Odoo modules.
add this in the top of your class

```
import logging
_logger = _logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

then where you want values to be logged in the logging of Odoo you could use.

```
_logger.error(yourvariableormessagehere)
```

or

```
_logger.warning(yourvariableormessagehere)
```

Using the standard Ubuntu terminal will make the error and warning messages pop out because of it't color. I don't know about other OSs terminals to be honest.

Answer (score 0):

You can do using python plugin with visual studio code. You can set break point as you want. It is as similar as debugging java in eclipse.

Detailed Information here:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging

[image: Example screenshot as you need]

Another similar way is winpdb (https://pypi.org/project/winpdb-reborn/) but it needs a line in your source code similar to eclipse+pydev.